# Advertisements blocked on most websites in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, adblock

On most websites the advertisements are blocked with the message "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". How do I fix this so the advertisements are shown?

Comment: Welcome to superuser! Please don't [sign your posts](http://superuser.com/faq#signatures). There's no need to sign as your post is already signed with your standard user card.

Comment: You have tagged this with "addblock". Do you have an "addblock" plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the latest flash framework [from here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)

*-- Why anyone would want those annoying advertisements to show is beyond me --*

Comment: Heh. Most of the time, I prefer an advertisement over an error message, myself. Apart from those really animated ones. >_>